# How to fix this error in IE regarding the from

Tags: javascript

I'm having this error:

`Object doesn't support 'from' property or method`

on the following line:

```js
const ids = Array.from(cbs).map(function(cb) {cb.getAttribute("data-item-id")});
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is [not implemented in IE11](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#browser_compatibility), so you'll need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#polyfill)

Comment: Therefore? how should i formulate my row?

Comment: @elfuso You add [the code that I linked to in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#polyfill) that will patch `Array`, adding support for `Array.from`

Comment: @elfuso   If you use a polyfill, it means you don't need to change any of your code, you just need to make sure the polyfill is loaded before your code.  PS: always use a polyfill if available, as modifying code to cope with this browser that browser is not fun.

Comment: @elfuso  I would also look into some form of transpiling, like babel / or Typescript, as you could even then do `[...cbs].map(` instead..  And transpiling will often add polyfills for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Array from is not supported by IE
https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_from

https://caniuse.com/ is you best friend in these cases.

Use a following polyfill to make it work.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#polyfill